# Convert read files in

Tags: python, plot

I want to plot multiple files from a folder. I am running into a problem regarding converting the data to something I understand how to plot.

First I read all the files in the folder:

```
for file_path in file_list:     # this for loop reads all files 
    with open(file_path) as f_input:
        sourcefiles.append(f_input.readlines())
```

I then trim each line in `sourcefiles` slightly to get rid of some headers

```
data = []
alldata = []
cutdata = []
    for i in range(0, length):
    l = len(sourcefiles[i])
    cdata = sourcefiles[i][320:l-2] 
    cutdata.append(cdata)
```

`cutdata` now includes `x` list of files with `y` lines. The first line looks like this:

```
['20.0000 10838.0000 1.0000\n', '20.0152 11226.0000 1.0000\n', '20.0304 11188.0000 1.0000\n', '20.0456 11133.0000 1.0000\n', '20.0608 11030.0000 1.0000\n', '20.0760 11275.0000 1.0000\n', '20.0912 11209.0000 1.0000\n', '20.1064 11127.0000 1.0000\n', '20.1216 11394.0000 1.0000\n', '20.1368 11030.0000 1.0000\n']
```

I want to plot the first two numbers in each line that are separated by white space. How should one go about plotting these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by splitting the string on whitespace and taking the first two fields:

```
x = []
y = []

for line in lines:
    a, b = line.split()[0:2]
    x.append(a)
    y.append(b)

plot(x, y)
```